# How can I build an attenuator for a SCART cable without damaging involved devices?

Tags: attenuator

I would like to attenuate the audio for one of my SCART cables.

I saw that it should be quite an easy project:
https://www.instructables.com/Homemade-RCA-Attenuator/

But I was wondering if something like this can impact the functionality of the SCART cable because, I assume, I will have to put the resistor also on the ground of the SCART so - being just a newbie hobbyst - I wanted to ask if this is a risk for other signals (video / others) included in the cable or if it can cause damage to the TV or the other device connected.

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Why it is not possible to adjust audio level on either the output (VCR?) or input (TV?) equipment? That would remove the need for a special cable.

Comment: Sadly not, @Justme It is a Nintendo Wii and it is proved that using attenuators will solve the issue. Lowering the volume on the tv still results in lowered volume clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be any issue. However you do need to make sure that the overall impedance of the attenuator, as seen by the source, is high enough. Also be aware that the input impedance of the receiving device will be across the second resistor, which may increase the attenuation if it is too low.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution...
I will use the values suggeted in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: those values should be fine, although he neglects the input impedance of the destination, which might be as low as 10-20k, and therefore would change the attenuation a lot. However that probably isn't critical. By the way if this answered your question you should accept it as an answer.

Comment: If I don't risk damaging the TV or the Console then I am just happy with the reply but I am not sure that you replied about that.
By "It should not be any issue" you mean that you are fairly sure about the impossibility of causing damage?
If so yes, I have my answer.

Comment: You certainly won't cause damage, as you are attenuating (provided that whatever you connect as input would not itself have caused damage - obviously if you are determined enough you can always find a way).